# Equivalent Capacitor

Tags: capacitor

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fT9xab.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm trying to find the equivalent capacitor for this diagram but I'm having a little trouble understanding what capacitor is parallel/in series to what capacitor.

I know the equations. From looking at this I believe C1 and C2 together are parallel as are C3 and C4 together. Would the resulting two equivalent capacitors then be in series with each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct. The wire across the "bar" of the H is (in an ideal circuit) topologically the same as a single point, so the network has two sets of parallel capacitors in series.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct. The capacitor C1 are in parallel with C2, as C3 are in parallel with C4.

*C1 // C2 = C1 + C2 = 500nF + 3.3uF = 3.8uF*

*C3 // C4 = C3 + c4 = 1uF + 2.2F = 2.200001F*

*1/C = 1/3.8uF + 1/2.2F*

***C = 3.8uF***

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcyqhD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>